# Is it possible to install MySQL extensions on Amazon RDS?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are about to migrate our existing system from local MySQL instances on the same EC2 to a proper remote Amazon-RDS.

Unfortunately there is a functionality called `Median` that MySQL is missing. Our existing code base is utilising [MySQL Infusion UDF](https://github.com/infusion/udf_infusion) to achieve calculating Medians.

1. Now we are in a dilemma, is it possible to install these extensions on RDS? I believe RDS is not really like a EC2 where you can just SSH in and install something.
2. Alternatively is there a way to do this `median` on MySQL without using extensions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If you require this extension, you will need to run your own MySQL instances.

Comment: I was also looking to see if it is possible to use UDFs in an RDS instance. Unfortunately, it isn't so I ended up using MySQL on my EC2 instance, where I have full control and can upload binary shared objects to MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at these links:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=320196

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

Comment: Posting just links is not an answer.